# Error in treating non-uniformly spaced data as uniform

Tags: data-analysis, signal-processing

In discussing smoothing filters,
[Numerical Recipes p. 772](http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html?pg=772) says

> ... irregularly sampled data, where the values $f_i$ are not uniformly spaced ...
>   one can simply pretend that the data points *are* equally spaced ...
>   a rough criterion:
>   If the change in $f$ across the full width of the $N$ point window is
>   less than $\sqrt{N/2}$ times the measurement noise on a single point,
>   then the cheap method can be used.

Where does this come from ?
It looks odd:
for $f(x) = \text{sin} ( 2 \pi f x )$ on [$-N \dots N]$,
change in $f = 2 < \sqrt{N/2}\ \sigma$ would require bigger $N$ for smaller $\sigma$ . Or have I misunderstood ?

Also, does this work for smoothing data on non-uniformly spaced 2d squares, 3d cubes ... ?

Added: https://gist.github.com/denis-bz/5957279 is a short Python program
that tries to elucidate this, for quantization noise
(sample at integers +- random-uniform( -1/2, 1/2 )).

Comment: I can only provide my scientific hunch on where to look... If the error in the x direction of the data is greater than the magnitude to the spacing, then shifting the grid doesn't really alter the shape of the data very much. I imaging by looking at the standard error (which is defined as $\sqrt(\sigma/N)$ by the way, similar function to the one you mention), that you can derive the condition yourself.